# How to create a table with a two-row header - PrawnPDF

Tags: ruby, prawn

I have simple table generated with PrawnPDF that looks like the one below

```
|h1|h2|h3|h4|
-------------
|d1|d2|d3|d4|
|d1|d2|d3|d4|
|d1|d2|d3|d4|
```

Generated by the code below

```
tb = [["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"],
      ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"],
      ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"],
      ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"]]

table(tb)do
  row(0).font_style = :bold
end
```

Now the header needs to be made by two rows as below

```
|text       |
|h1|h2|h3|h4|
-------------
|d1|d2|d3|d4|
|d1|d2|d3|d4|
|d1|d2|d3|d4|
```

I have tried to make a subtable and to use it as the header but it does not span all the table. It looks like

```
|text       |
|h1|h2|h3|h4|
----------------------
|d1         |d2|d3|d4|
|d1         |d2|d3|d4|
|d1         |d2|d3|d4|
```

and no row is bold.

Here the code so far

```
text = make_cell(content: 'text', colspan: 4)
header_array = [[text], ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"]]
header = make_table(header_array)

tb = [[header],
      ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"],
      ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"],
      ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"]]

table(tb)do
  row(0).font_style = :bold
end
```

Any ideas how can I span the header?

**PS I'm using prawn version 1.3.0 and prawn-table 0.2.2**

Thanks

UPDATE - Based on Florent answer, if you want/need to pass a block to the table.

```
header_text = [[{content: "Text", colspan: 4}]]
tb = [["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"],
  ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"],
  ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"],
  ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"]]

table(header_text + tb)do
  row(0).font_style = :bold
  self.header = 2
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dit you try to use the header param ?

```
header_text = [[{content: "Text", colspan: 4}]]
tb = [["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"],
  ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"],
  ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"],
  ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4"]]

table(header_text + tb, header: 2)do
  row(0).font_style = :bold
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure where the `header =2` comes from but even if the table looks fine the header  (2 rows) is not repeated on each page. Using 1.3

Comment: it turned out you must add `self` to make it works `self.header = 2`.

Comment: updated my answer with the correct syntax (just tested)